# Angular Sort columns

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sorting

Now this is what i'm working with because i can't get it to work. I don't think it's bad in anyway but still:

In my app.component.html i've got:

```
    <table border="1">
        <!-- ADD HEADERS -->
        <tr>
            <th><a href="#" (click)="send()">Name</a>
            </th>
            <th>Goverment form</th>

        </tr>

    </table>
```

In my app.component.ts I've got:

```
         }
         return 0;
    });
     }



--------
Data:
-------

    export interface Country {
        Name:string;
        GovernmentForm:string;

    }
    export class AppComponent {
      public Countries: Country[];
```

Comment: What issue are you having with the code above? What is the behaviour you're seeing?

Comment: It does not sort my tables correctly. I want to be able to click on Name and have the table sort name by asc/desc order. However I'm not getting the correct results

Comment: Then in your sort function, you need to be comparing the `.name` property, not the entire country object

Comment: hey this doesn't seem to work I get the error "Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined"

Comment: Can you add a sample of your data please? I will add an answer below to show you what I mean.

Comment: export interface Country {
 Name:string;;
 GovernmentForm:string;
}

Comment: I added it now in the question hopefully this is what u mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your sort function to compare the `.Name` property, instead of the whole object. You can do this like so:

```
this.Countries = this.Countries.sort((n1, n2) => {
  if (n1.Name > n2.Name) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (n1.Name < n2.Name) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
});
```

Comment: I've been banging my head in to the wall for like the last hour trying to solve this, u made it so easy for me to understand now thanks!!!!